# Using custom Logging action in Play 2.2.x

Tags: playframework, logback

All examples I can find to use a custom Logger in Play Framework for play.Logger.debug(), play.Logger.info() etc (with the default static class Logger, not with any created instances) need to write a self-written class into conf/logger.xml. This does not work in development mode, I get an Exception

```
 Could not create an Appender of type [my.example.log.LoggerConnector].ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type my.example
.log.LoggerConnector
        at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type my.example.log.LoggerConnector
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:73)
```

...

configuration looks like

<appender name="MYEXAMPLELOGGER" class="my.example.log.LoggerConnector">
  </appender>

and when I run the application via `start`, it works.

Does anybody know a way to register a Logger at runtime? The logger has to be instanciated after booting the application, since it should connect to some existing functionality.

Any hint, any help?

Comment: Are you saying that your custom appender (LoggerConnector) works in a standalone application which just uses logback but doesn't work when used in play framework? You also state another problem of registering a logger at runtime. Is that second problem?

Comment: With play (which uses sbt, simple build tool) there are different possibilities to start the application, "start" and "run". "start" is near deployment mode, "run" is development mode. With "start" my LoggerConnector is working, with "run" it is not. I hope to find a way to register it not at boot time, but at runtime to go around this startup problem.

Comment: Can you post your LoggerConnector class?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d03b4cbefb394de8b9f4

Comment: I first tried it in my "normal" package, and "package log;" was a search for a fix. Link had an error, new link is  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cccf32c5856fb863d94d